# Angular - Select box - set selected entry from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select box, defined as follows:

```
 <select ng-model="selectedSupplier" ng-options="supplier.name for supplier in suppliers">
 </select>
```

IN my controller, I have the a button which, although not doing anything useful, serves to explain a problem I'm having changing the selected value in the controller:

When this function is executed, the options in the select box are set, and the selected option is set:

```
$scope.foo = function() {
    var foos = [{"id":1,"name":"No 1"},{"id":2,"name":"No 2"},{"id":3,"name":"No 3"},{"id":4,"name":"No 4"}];
    $scope.suppliers = foos;
    $scope.selectedSupplier = foos[2];
}
```

But I changed the function to be like this, it still sets the options, but the selected option is a new blank option, none of my defined ones:

```
$scope.foo = function() {
    var foos = [{"id":1,"name":"No 1"},{"id":2,"name":"No 2"},{"id":3,"name":"No 3"},{"id":4,"name":"No 4"}];
    $scope.suppliers = foos;
    $scope.selectedSupplier = {"id":3,"name":"No 3"};
}
```

What's going on here? How can I set the selected option using an object other than the original?

Comment: can't you look up the object somehow from the list (match by id or name) and use that to set selectedSupplier?  Otherwise if you create a new object, they are not going to match and they won't get selected.

Answer (score 2):

This is an equality/identity issue. The literal

```
 $scope.selectedSupplier = {"id":3,"name":"No 3"};
```

Is not the same as the object in your foos array. Although they contain the same data, they are 2 different references.

```
$scope.selectedSupplier === foos[2] // false
```

You correctly reference the object in your array in your first example.

```
$scope.selectedSupplier = foos[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngOptions` directive handles arrays and objects differently: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
$scope.selectedSupplier = {"id":3,"name":"No 3"};
```

You are assigning an independant object into `$scope.selectedSupplier`, which is not part of the options list. There is no deep comparison behind the scenes - in case of complex objects, you must assign the actual object itself.

If you want  for example to assign selected value based on the id property, have such code:

```
var idToAssign = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.suppliers.length; i++) {
    var curSupplier = $scope.suppliers[i];
    if (curSupplier.id == idToAssign) {
        $scope.selectedSupplier = curSupplier;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with removing `"`  around object keys (`id` not `"id"`) as it is not required in javascript and it worked.

```
  $scope.foo = function() {
       var foos = [{id:1,name:"No 1"},{id:2,name:"No 2"},{id:3,name:"No 3"},{id:4,name:"No 4"}];
       $scope.suppliers = foos;
       $scope.selectedSupplier = {id:3,name:"No 3"};
  };
```

if you have no issue removing quotes then it can be a solution

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Since the question shows an MCVE, and the real app I'm having the equivalent problem with receives a JSON response from server, I prefer to leave the quotes on because the server response has quotes.

Comment: You can parse your json data to simple javascript objects like this `JSON.parse('{"Id": 1, "Name": "No 1"}')` which will produce `{ Id: 1, Name: "No 1"}`